# How to send uploded document via an url using symfony5

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, symfony5

I'm trying to send a document uploaded to the maarch signature via symfony. I have already written my codes in pure php and I would like to adapt them on symfony but I don't know how to do it. Here are the codes written in php.

form.php

```
<?php
    $url = "http://ggrand:maarch@169.176.61.102:5600/rest/users";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Envoi d'un document dans le parapheur</title>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jsonObj =<?php echo $response;?>
    </script>

    <body>
        <form action="processJson_tableau.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Titre du document</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Référence du document</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="reference" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description du document</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Type d'action</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" id="sign" name="mode" value="sign" />
                        <label for="male">Signature</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" id="note" name="mode" value="note" />
                        <label for="female">Anotation</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" id="visa" name="mode" value="visa" />
                        <label for="female">Visa</label><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Joindre le fichier</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="encodedDocument" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Prénom et Nom de l'expéditeur</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="sender" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nom et prénom du destinataire</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="dropDown" name="processingUser"></select>
                        
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var myDDL = document.getElementById("dropDown");
                            var str1 = " ";

                            for (i = 0; i < jsonObj.users.length; i++) {
                                var option = document.createElement("option");
                                option.text = jsonObj.users[i].firstname.concat(str1, jsonObj.users[i].lastname);
                                option.value = jsonObj.users[i].login;
                                try {
                                    myDDL.options.add(option);
                                } catch (e) {
                                    alert(e);
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Upload"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

processJson_tableau.php

```
<?php

    $currentDirectory = getcwd();
    $uploadDirectory = "/";

    $errors = []; // Store errors here

    $fileExtensionsAllowed = ['jpeg','jpg','png','pdf']; // These will be the only file extensions allowed 

    $fileName = $_FILES['encodedDocument']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['encodedDocument']['size'];
    $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['encodedDocument']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['encodedDocument']['type'];
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));

    $uploadPath = $currentDirectory . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName); 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensionsAllowed)) {
        $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a JPEG or PNG file";
      }

      if ($fileSize > 4000000) {
        $errors[] = "File exceeds maximum size (4MB)";
      }

      if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

        if ($didUpload) {
          echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
        } else {
          echo "An error occurred. Please contact the administrator.";
        }
      } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
          echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
      }

    }

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $reference = $_POST['reference'];
    $desc = $_POST['description'];
    $encodedDoc = $fileName;
    $sender = $_POST['sender'];
    $processingUser = $_POST['processingUser'];
    $mode = $_POST['mode'];

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('doc1.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
    {
        // Add files to the zip file
        $zip->addFile($encodedDoc);
     
        // All files are added, so close the zip file.
        $zip->close();
    }

    // Get the file and convert into string 
    $zip_f = file_get_contents('doc1.zip'); 
      
    // Encode the zip file string data into base64 
    $data = base64_encode($zip_f); 
      
    // Display the output 
    //echo $data; 

    $puser = array('processingUser' =>$processingUser, 'mode' => $mode);

    $document = array('title' =>$title, 'reference' =>$reference, 'description' =>$desc,  'encodedDocument' =>$data, 'sender' =>$sender,
    'workflow'=>array($puser)
        );

    $json_response = json_encode($document);

    //API Url
    $url = 'http://ggrand:maarch@169.176.61.102:5600/rest/documents';
     
    //Initiate cURL.
    $ch = curl_init($url);
     
    //Encode the array into JSON.
    $jsonDataEncoded = $json_response;
     
    //Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     
    //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
     
    //Set the content type to application/json
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
     
    //Execute the request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    unlink('doc1.zip');
    unlink($fileName);
?>
```

Here is the controller code that I started to write on symfony, but now I'm stuck, I don't know how to move forward.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Upload;
use App\Form\UploadType;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class FileController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="accueil")
     */

   public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $upload = new Upload();

        $form = $this->createForm(UploadType::class, $upload);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $manager->persist($upload);
            $manager->flush();

            //$enc = $upload->getDocument();
            //$file = base64_encode($enc);
            $file = $upload->getDocument();
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
            $file->move($this->getParameter('upload_directory'), $fileName);
            $enc = base64_encode($file);
            $upload->setDocument($fileName);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('accueil');

        }

        return $this->render('file/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to show the part where I display the form using symfony?

Answer (score 0):

To upload and download files, you can use [Vich uploader bundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) that permit you to:

> - Automatically name and save a file to a configured directory
> - Inject the file back into the entity or document when it is loaded from the
>   datastore as an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File
> - Delete the file from the file system upon removal of the entity or document from the datastore
> - Templating helpers to generate public URLs to the file

The full documentation is here: [Vich uploader documentation](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/index.md).

So, to add this bundle to your own code, you should add an entity that will store the file properties and the reference of the file itself. The bundle provides an Object that helps you to store the file where you want.